# Update constraint in UITableVeiwCell

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I have a view in UITableViewCell , height of view can be 90 or 60 depending upon condition. I made a IBOutlet to height constraint and updating its value in cellForRow method , but getting layout waring in logs. Do I need to call any method like layoutIfNeeded in cellForRow after updating the constant ?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewDelegate` has this method, that determines the height of cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Implement this method and depending on you condition return the required height.

Apart from this you need to make sure that your constraints don't break, when supplied with this height.

So here are the steps,

1. Drag drop a `UITableViewCell` from 'Object Library'.
2. Select the cell and from 'Size Inspector', set the 'Row Height' to 60.
3. Set you subview and their contstraints. Don't put a height constraints on the 'Content View' of the table view cell.
4. Implement the above mentioned method and return height as 60.

If this same cell can have height 90, set 90 in step two, four and make sure constraints don't break when you set 90 in step two.